# C# UWP Populating and accessing a nested list

Tags: c#, list, object, uwp, nested-loops

I am creating an app that stores and displays weather details.

In this snippet `result` is a list of objects (40 objects, 8 weather forecasts daily over 5 days) that I am separating into days and hours. I am using a nested list to display a list of hourly forecasts within a list of days(each `sortedDay` list has its own `sortedHours` list within it.

When I print the output every object has the same value and  `Debug.WriteLine(" -");` is being called after each print (39 times when it should only be called max 5 times)

```
//create a list of weatherController lists to hold each day
List<List<WeatherController>> sortedDays =new List<List<WeatherController>>();

//create a list of weatherController objects to hold each hourly interval
List<WeatherController> sortedHours = new List<WeatherController>();

// a base time
DateTime prevDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01");
int counter = 0;

// iterate through result list  
foreach (var wCount in result.list)
{
    // if the date is greater than the previous date add the sortedHours to sortedDays
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(result.list[counter].dt_txt) > prevDate && counter!=0)
    {
        sortedDays.Add(sortedHours);
        sortedHours.Clear();
    }
    WeatherController wController= new WeatherController();

    wController.dtime=result.list[counter].dt_txt;
    wController.temp = result.list[counter].main.temp;
    wController.humidity= result.list[counter].main.humidity;
    wController.desc = result.list[counter].weather[0].description;
    wController.windSpeed= result.list[counter].wind.speed;
    sortedHours.Add(wController);

    prevDate = Convert.ToDateTime(result.list[counter].dt_txt);
    counter++;

}

// test List of list Structure
int xCount=0,yCount=0;

foreach(var sd in sortedDays)
{
    foreach(var sh in sortedHours)
    {
        // DEBUG
        Debug.WriteLine(sortedDays[xCount][yCount].ToString());
        yCount++;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(" -");
    xCount++;
    yCount = 0;
}
```

A snippet of the output:

```
dtime:2018-03-05 21:00:00 temp:274.687 humidity:100 desc:light rain windpeed:3.61

-
dtime:2018-03-05 21:00:00 temp:274.687 humidity:100 desc:light rain windpeed:3.61
-
dtime:2018-03-05 21:00:00 temp:274.687 humidity:100 desc:light rain windpeed:3.61
-
dtime:2018-03-05 21:00:00 temp:274.687 humidity:100 desc:light rain windpeed:3.61
-
```

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach` and then not using the `wCount` (or `sd`, or `sh`)? You might as well just use `for` loops...

Comment: As the data is being read from an api so the size is subject to change ,Also wCount is an object and not an integer value, also will be split into separate methods

Comment: I know, my point was you could use `wCount` instead of `result.list[counter]`. The size is `result.list.Length` (or `.Count()`), right...?

Comment: Oh right ,I don't feel that is the issue as when I debug it is taking in the correct values from `result` and assigning them correclty to `wController` but the issue seems to be when it is added to the list

Comment: Right, it's just something to think about for making your code easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that you are reusing one single instance of `sortedHours` for each result entry. Because `List<T>` is a reference type, the variable points to the location in memory where the data is stored. Because you `Clear` and `Add` to the same instance in each iteration, after the last "round" it will contain only the very last item from the list.

Second problem is that the last item in the input is not processed, because the `foreach` will end and the `sortedHours` list will contain some items that were not yet assigned to any day.

Finally there is problem in the date comparison:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(result.list[counter].dt_txt) > prevDate
```

This does **not compare dates only**. It compares **date and time**. This means that it the if will execute every time. To compare dates only, you would have to nullify the time portion of the date, which can be done most easily by using the `Date` property:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(result.list[counter].dt_txt).Date > prevDate.Date
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I understand now , I can adapt it to create a new instance of `wController` each time but as for creating a new `sortedHours` list I cannot get my head around how that would be implemented as a new list ?

Comment: Basically, when you call `Add( sortedHours )`, you add a pointer to the memory location to the `sortedDays` list. Right on the next line you call clear `sortedHours` - which essentially clears the variable, but because the item in `sortedDays` list points to the very same variable, it now basically points to an empty collection. You can see this very well if you put a breakpoint right after the `Clear` line - if you hover over the `sortedDays` variable and investigate the added item, you will see it is suddenly empty - that's because it is the same instance as `sortedHours` :-)

Comment: The solution would be to do `sortedHours = new List<WeatherController>()` instead of `Clear`. That will create a new instance and leave the one already used intact.

Comment: As an analogy, imagine you have a shortcut to a file on your harddisk. If you modify the contents of the file, the change will be reflected in the shortcut as well, because it points to this very same file.

Comment: Thanks that has eliminated most the issues, just getting 'index out of range' now on the debug line

Comment: That is because you are enumerating the `sortedHours` variable, whereas you actually want to enumerate `foreach ( var sh in sd ) ` - basically enumerating the hours in the currently enumerated day

Comment: Problem solved and knowledge gained thank you for all the help

Comment: Glad it helped :-)! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the Grey checkmark ✅ to mark the question as solved. Happy coding!